# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using

Tags: numpy, python-3.4

```
from __future__ import division
from numpy import *
import matplotlib as plt
import os

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear() # clear screen

meu=1e-05 # exponential form
x1=load(char('neweeg.txt'))
x=x1(arange(1,5000))
xx=x1(arange(5001,10000))
N=length(x)
X=zeros(4,1)
w=rand(4,1)

for n in arange(1,N).reshape(-1):
    X[arange(2,end())]=X(arange(1,end() - 1))
    X[1]=x(n)
    y[n]=w.T * X
    e[n]=x(n) - y(n)
    w=w + meu * e(n) * X
    J[n]=e(n) * e(n)

MSE=mean(J,1)

plt.plot(10 * log10(MSE))
plt.figure
plt.plot(x)
hold(char('on'))
plt.plot(y,char('r'))
plt.figure
plot(xx - (e).T)
hold(char('on'))
plt.plot(xx,char('r'))
```

**ERROR**

```
file "/home/pi/Documents/final.py", line 10, in <module>
x1=load(char('neweeg.txt'))
typeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: please format your code properly using [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: sir i don't understand what you'r saying, at line 8 it shows error

Comment: sir kindly do me a favour, i m working on my final year project,

Comment: why are you using `char('newegg')`? Are you expected to convert it to `char` type?

Comment: sir i have a text file neweeg in which 10008 random no's

Comment: could you show/attach part of your 'neweeg.txt' file? Try to use `numpy.loadtxt` instead of `numpy.load(numpy.char)`

Comment: would you plz give me your email so i send you this file

Comment: neweeg file:

45.13841
46.68014
48.22187
49.42099
49.84925
49.5923
49.24969
48.99274
48.99274
48.99274
49.16404
50.44881
52.76141
55.84487
58.50007
59.18528
57.7292
54.56009
50.02056
45.22406
41.11279
38.88584
38.9715
40.59888
42.56886
43.76799
43.85364
42.82582
40.59888
37.51542
34.60326
32.37632
31.43415
32.37632
34.77456
37.68672
40.25627
42.31191
44.28189
46.42319
48.47883
49.24969
48.22187
45.65232
42.05495
38.20063

Comment: You have to many errors in your code try to execute line by line and fix them all.

Comment: actually we have converted matlab code on python. can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the immediate error is because you are using char() as if it was a function. It's not obvious what you intend by this (there is a python built in function chr() to produce characters from integers)

It's then not clear what you are trying to do. numpy.load() will read a pickled array produced by numpy.save() but if it's a text file then numpy.loadtxt() would seem more relevant. But then x1 would be an ndarray so it doesn't make sense to use it as function with x1() in the next two lines. Also is length() len()? rand(4,1) random.randint(1,4) or numpy.random.randint(1,4)? As Anton says you just have to work your way through fixing errors, looking things up in the docs.

Finally, it will make things much clearer to you and others if you don't import * but prefix each method by the name of the module you think you are using.

Comment: In neweeg.txt 1008 numeric values, i want to assign this 1008 value in x1 and 1-5000 value assign to other variable and 5000-10000 values assign to other. if i do wrong plz help howw to resolve this.. i m new i realy dont know how to use modules in python, this code is basicaly converted from matlab code, in matlab work 100% fine,

Comment: x1 = np.loadtxt('neweeg.txt')
x = np.arange(1, 5001)
xx = np.arange(5000, 10001) However matlab must be a margelous language if it can cope with introducing subscripted variables such as y[], e[] andJ[] like that. Maybe it would be clearer if you posted your working matlab code, or else explain in words what your code is attempting to do. Generally speaking if you use a python loop with numpy you know you are doing things the wrong way! (But I've still no idea what you are trying to do)

Comment: i have posted my matlab code, it will help you, i need your help. plz

Answer (score 0):

This is Matlab code working 100% good. and trying to convert it into Python

```
clc;
    close all;
    clear all;


    meu = 0.00001;
    x1=load('neweeg.txt');
    x = x1(1:5000);
    xx =x1 (5001:10000);
    N = length(x);

    X = zeros(4,1);
    w = rand(4,1);

    for n = 1:N

        X(2:end) = X(1:end-1);
        X(1) = x(n);

        y(n) = w'*X;
        e(n) = x(n) - y(n);   
        w = w + meu*e(n)*X;
        J(n) = e(n)*e(n);
    end

    MSE = mean(J,1);
    plot(10*log10(MSE))
    title('MSE')

    figure
    plot(x);hold on; plot(y,'r')
    title('X and Y')

    figure;
    plot(xx-(e)')
    hold on
    plot(xx,'r') 
    title('XX-(e) or XX')
```